# What happens to my data on a VM after my trial account expires?

Tags: virtual-machine, azure

I had created a VM using Azure free trial account, my account expired earlier that the 30 days as my credits were finished. I didn't get a change to delete my data, does anyone know what happens to the data on my virtual machine ? Any trusted source mentions that on the internet ?

Answer (score 1):

From the [Free Trial page](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/offers/ms-azr-0044p/) itself:

> **Resource Commitment**
>
> For any subscriptions of this offer that are not incurring charges and
>   are inactive for over 90 days, we reserve the right to remove any
>   compute resources including hosted service(s), virtual machines and
>   websites. Please note that no data would be deleted and customers can
>   redeploy at any time. We will also provide advance notice prior to
>   removing any compute resources.